# How to set variable value to be a new row python

Tags: python, row, padding

My code:

```
test_str = '''
(()(code)())


((t(e(x(t(()


()(co)de)('''
countofrightbrackets = 0
countofleftbrackets = 0
blockcount = 0
myDict = {};
for i in test_str:
    if i == '(':
        countofrightbrackets = countofrightbrackets + 1
    if i == ')':
        countofleftbrackets = countofleftbrackets + 1
    if i == '':
        blockcount = blockcount + 1
        if countofrightbrackets == countofleftbrackets:
          myDict.update({blockcount:'True'});
        else:
          myDict.update({blockcount:'False'});
  

print (myDict)
```

My program is counting () and if count of ( = ) then save to dictionary True. Else false. In test_str I have some blocks - they are dissociated with 2 new rows. In if i == '': I want to show, that if I = 2 new rows, then compete the code. Also I need to check are brackets are at correct positions - like ()()() is true and ())( is false. How to do this?

Example:

```
Input:
(()()())


((((((()


()())(

Output:
1: True 2: False 3: False
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to ask. Please show: 1) a small enough `test_str` that we could easily solve the problem by hand (but it should still show off any hard cases); 2) *exactly* what the output is when you use that `test_str`; 3) *exactly* what the output *should be* and *why*; 4) *how that is different*.

Comment: Do the following links solve your problem? https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-parentheses/ https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-for-balanced-parentheses-in-an-expression/

Comment: I need to subscribe to see solution. But yes, it answers - can you copy and paste the code as answer? Thanks!